# In groovy script how to build dynamically parse and build JSON

Tags: groovy

Assuming I am having json input and output payload like this.

```
{
  "env": {
    "CO2": "2",
    "NO2": "3"
  }
}
```

output:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "Environment": {
      "carbon-di-oxide": "2",
      "nitrogen-di-oxide": "3"
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose the mapping json is :

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "payload.Environment.carbon-di-oxide": "env.co2",
    "payload.Environment.nitrogen-di-oxide": "env.co"
  }
}
```

So, based on the mapping json how can I create dynamic json.
I have written script like this:

```
import groovy.json.*;

def input='{\"env\": {\"CO2\": \"2\",\"NO2\": \"3\"}}';
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def finalJson = jsonSlurper.parseText('{}') ;
def inputJson= jsonSlurper.parseText(input) ;
finalJson["carbon-di-oxide"]=inputJson.env.CO2;
finalJson["nitrogen-di-oxide"]=inputJson.env.NO2;
def content=new JsonBuilder( finalJson).toPrettyString();
println("content-->"+content)
```

but here how can I pass nested output like `payload.Environment.carbon-di-oxide` dynamically,and create the ouput based on mapping json like in javascript. First the groovy script will be generated based on the mapping json. Then input will be feeded to produce the output as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the keys and values of your mapping json at the `.` and walk through the resulting lists to collect the values / create the output structure.

The below is based on your sample code.
**Note** that I have fixed your mapping to uppercase where your input is uppercase and `nitrogen-di-oxide` from `CO` to `NO2`.

```
import groovy.json.*;

def mappingInput = """
{
  "mapping": {
    "payload.Environment.carbon-di-oxide": "env.CO2",
    "payload.Environment.nitrogen-di-oxide": "env.NO2"
  }
}
"""
def input='{\"env\": {\"CO2\": \"2\",\"NO2\": \"3\"}}';
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def inputJson= jsonSlurper.parseText(input) ;
def mapping = jsonSlurper.parseText(mappingInput)

def output = [:]
mapping.mapping.each{k,v ->
    def inVal = inputJson
    v.split(/\./).each{inKey->
        inVal = inVal[inKey]
    }
    def keyParts = k.split(/\./)
    def current = output
    if (keyParts.size() > 1) {
        keyParts[0..-2].each{outKey ->
            if (!current.keySet().contains(outKey)) {
                current[outKey] = [:]
            }
            current = current[outKey]
        }
    }
    current[keyParts[-1]] = inVal
}
def finalJson = new JsonBuilder(output).toPrettyString()

println finalJson
```

Output would be

```
{
    "payload": {
        "Environment": {
            "carbon-di-oxide": "2",
            "nitrogen-di-oxide": "3"
        }
    }
}
```